# Insert bytes at the beginning of an existing file without overwriting existing bytes

Tags: java, android, file-io, bytestream

How can I add bytes to an existing file without:

- overwriting existing bytes
- reading the file

Comment: Keep the file on the disk in reverse order for use, appending to the end (which is actually the beginning).  Use a function to access the file in reverse order when other code needs to access it normally.

Comment: why the close  vote? what part of the problem stztement is unclear? Requestor wants an efficient way to prepend to a disk file

Comment: I dont know why the close vote? what part of the problem stztement is unclear?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you have described it you're going to need operating-system support to do that
.
As far as I know this sort of thing is only easy for files stored on punched cards.
or if you can add a shim between the userspace and the filesystem.

The best you can hope to do in java is override the file reading an writing code your 
own application is using to fake the presence of the extra bytes.

I hope you're not trying to corrupt perfectly good text files by adding *UTF-8 BOM* to the start.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: some problems can be solved by a code sample. this is not one of them

Comment: @Jasen thanks for your help your answer is almost correct. Thanks Again. and I don't know what happed to other people who vote down